# Different results for postfix operator (x++) in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, operators, variable-assignment, postfix-operator

I'm learning web development, and I got puzzled by the strange behavior of a **certain code** in JavaScript and PHP.

JavaScript

```
n = 10
n = n - n++
console.log(n) // outputs 0
```

PHP

```
$n = 10;
$n = $n - $n++;
echo $n; // outputs 1
```

I know that, x++ increments x *after use* and ++x increments x *before use*. So, `n` is assigned a value of 0 in second statement, but then will x increase or not?

I guess that it's what making the difference in the outputs, but I'm not sure.

Comment: have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/de/language.operators.precedence.php

Comment: I think [this should cover it pretty well](https://gist.github.com/nikic/6699370). It's also by [@NikiC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385378/nikic), a PHP dev. Not posting it as an answer because I'm not sure how to do it without pasting the entire thing.

Comment: @FatFreddy, just a minor thing - it would normally be better to link to an English version of the manual - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php